# Unable to load class: phpfox/session/handler/default - include/library/phpfox/error/error.class.php (95)

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpfox

I am getting error for my phpfox website, when I migrated it to new server which is ubuntu 14.04, when I have enabled debuging, the following error shown on the website page:

> User Error: Unable to load class: phpfox/session/handler/default -
>   include/library/phpfox/error/error.class.php (95)

Comment: Did you enabled debugging before migration ? Can you make sure that the problem is new ?